# How do I open GitKraken after installation on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, gitkraken

It seems that this is a real issue. In [How to Install GitKraken](https://support.gitkraken.com/how-to-install), they point to a `%APPDATA%/.gitkraken` folder. Once there, you have "profiles" and "service" folders and "config", "log" and "secFile" files. Inside those folders, there are no signs of an executable. It's not under Program Files, nor in the PATH environment variable, it's nowhere to be found. If you install it **again**, it opens normally and logged in your profile, but after closing it, there's no way to open it again. There are no shortcuts.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

By default GitKraken is installed to your local app data folder. You can find the executable file inside `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gitkraken\app-<app-version>`

As of this writing, the latest version is 2.0.1 so the exe will be `%LOCALAPPDATA%\gitkraken\app-2.0.1\gitkraken.exe`

And easier way to open the software would be using the shortcut in the start menu:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! For some reason, the Axosoft folder wasn't created on the start menu. %LOCALAPPDATA% is a weird place to install a software. I think it's because it's cross-platform.

Comment: The other reason for installing inside that folder is to avoid requesting admin privileges by the installer.